# and condition unpredictable in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

The following does not evaluate correctly and shows a field even when the cond4 is not met

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!and(cond1, cond2,cond3, cond4)}">
SHOW A FIELD
 </aura:if>
```

However, when I put cond4 in the front of the and, then it works as expected and does not show the field when cond4 is not met.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!and(cond4, cond2,cond3, cond1)}">
SHOW A FIELD
 </aura:if>
```

any clues

Comment: I have observed that if you put it this way, it works consistently : `<aura:if isTrue="{!and(cond1, and(cond2,and(cond3, cond4)))}">`

Comment: Nice hack @Sarang. Yet to try but technically, it is still 2 conditions in one 'and'. I am going to use this hack and test. Thank you.

Comment: 2 conditions are fine. What it requires is 2 parameters in 1 `and` function. Just FYI, if you are using `OR` you can use `||` operator and this works multiple times. So the issue is with AND function only.